# Scanning for Character error?

Tags: java, dictionary, methods, java.util.scanner

I'm scanning a file and trying to track the amount of times a character comes up.

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> getCountMap(Scanner in){
    Map<Character, Integer> wordCountMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();

    while (in.hasNext()){
        Character word = in.next().toLowerCase();
        //CHAR HAS BEEN SEEN, ADD
        if(wordCountMap.containsKey(word)){
            int count = wordCountMap.get(word);
            wordCountMap.put(word, count + 1);
        }
        //NEW CHAR, CREATE
        else    {
            wordCountMap.put(word, 1);
        }
    }
return wordCountMap;
}
```

I'm getting an error for `Character word = in.next().toLowerCase();`

I checked java api, and characters definitely have access to `toLowerCase()`. However the api for Scanners says

> hasNext() 
>   Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.

Does that mean a scanner can't scan through per character?
Shouldn't this just scan through the characters, adding them to the map and increasing the count each time it see's something?

Final note : This code runs just fine if every `Character` is replaced with `String`. I can get a word count no problem. Char count, not so much.

***Main Method*** (In case this is required)

```
public static void main(Character[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    //read the book into the map
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("moby.txt"));
    Map<Character, Integer> wordCountMap = getCountMap(in);


    for (Character word: wordCountMap.keySet()){
        int count = wordCountMap.get(word);
        if (count > OCCURRENCES){
            System.out.println(word + " occurs " + count + " times.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `in.next().toLowerCase()` returns a `Character` object?

Comment: @TNT I'm not entirely sure. I just checked API and I can't actually even find in.next. I know that it works for strings... where would I look to figure that out? 
When I'm dealing with strings, my scanner (in) fills a string with the next value. So maybe it doesn't take a char...

Comment: @TNT,
"The java.util.Scanner.next() method finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. "

Comment: Is a token only a string?

Comment: It is a string only thing

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`Javadocs` for the `next()` method of `java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--):

> ```
> public String next()
> ```
>
> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

As can be seen, this method does not return `Character`; it returns `String`, which is why you're getting that error.

A *token* is basically a substring that falls between two instances of a delimiter. The default delimiter of a `Scanner` is a whitespace object (`\s`, `\t`, `\n`, etc.). So the Scanner goes through the file and each invocation of `next()` will return the next sequence of characters that is between what is seen as a delimiter.

So what you could do is change the delimiter so that the Scanner counts each character in the file as a token, though that's a bit complex. What you could do instead is make use of the fact that the `String` class has a method [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--), which returns the sequence of characters in the string as an array. You can count the individual characters a lot easier that way:

```
String word = in.next().toLowerCase();
char[] charsInWord = word.toCharArray();
// ...
```

Comment: I was actually about to do a charAt loop, however toCharArray is much smoother.